# Data Scraping xPath finding <tr> <td> with string

Tags: html, xpath

Im trying to scrape data off this site

http://webapps.nyc.gov:8084/cics/f704/f403001i?DET=1-00835-0041

All the data is built off a single table using tr td
I need to scrape the whole row containing 202 and the relative Account Type, Period Begin Date, Due Date

I got the ALL the 202 tr row using

xpath: //td/font[contains(.,'202')]/../..

I cant figure out how to get the relative account type,  period begin date, due date

Any Ideas?  Thank you so much

Comment: Could you post an xml sample? Would make it a lot easier to help, and it would make the question more useful to users with similar problems, who come across the question later on.

Comment: The link to the site is not working (the page never loads).

Answer (score 0):

No need to go up the tree with `..`, just start your expression with `tr` and check for `td/font` inside it:

```
//tr[td/font[contains(., '202')]]
```

To get all the cells inside the row:

```
//tr[td/font[contains(., '202')]]/td
```

Comment: I only need infomation with the tr row with '202'.  The problem is I can't figure out how to get the account type, period begin date, due date relative to the 202 value

Comment: @ParkBroom sure, as answered, `//tr[contains(td/font, '202')]` would give you the start  - the row in which `202` is present. For instance, `//tr[contains(td/font, '202')]/td[6]/font/text()` should give you the Period End/In Date..

Comment: @ParkBroom I've updated the answer with what is actually working for me. What programming language are you using at the moment? I can provide you with a working sample in Python+lxml, would that we alright?

Comment: @alexce, the code works but what i want is:

This is example is based on the first 202 (0461442016121),
Account Type (first column), would be "ELEV" 
Period Begin Date (third column), would be "07/15/2014"
Due Date (forth column), would be "10/01/2014"

Pretty much i need the data set to be like
ELEV, 07/15/2014, 10/01/2014, 202, 0461442016121

Comment: @ParkBroom what programming language and XML parser are you using?

Comment: @alexce, http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html
I think it may be easier just to insert all the rows into a database and loop through all the rows instead

Comment: @ParkBroom sorry, I understand the logic that needs to be applied to solve it, but I have difficulties implementing it using the DOM crawler symphony component since my PHP skills are quite rusty and for some reasons preceding and preceding-sibling axis are not working as I expect them to work. Anyway, the expression provided in the answer points to the row containing 202. To get the account type, use something like `preceding-sibling::tr[normalize-space(td[2]/font)]/td[2]/font`.